# ArrayList - Add Elements, Passively Skipping Redundant Elements

Tags: java, collections

Let says I have two arraylists:

```
List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
arryOne.add("Huey");
arryOne.add("Dewey");
arryOne.add("Louie");

List<String> arryTwo = new ArrayList<>();
arryTwo.add("Dewey");
arryTwo.add("Stuie");
```

Is there some convenient API or relatively simple way to add "Stuie" to arryOne while ignoring the redundant "Dewey" element?

I am sure I can brute force perform the add/ignore but was hoping someone might know of a convenience means through collections API or similar to do this in just a few lines of code. Thanks!

Comment: You should probably be using a `Set` instead of a list if you want to avoid duplicate elements. Then adding an element that already exists is a no-op.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't, because List is a datatype that more or less explicitly means: Can contain duplicates.

In other words, List, if anything, has baked in that the second `Dewey` *is not* redundant:

```
arr.addAll(arryTwo);
```

*should* result in: `[Huey, Dewey, Louie, Dewey, Stuie]`.

Other data types are what you need. For example, a LinkedHashSet:

```
var set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
var arr1 = List.of("Huey", "Dewey", "Louie");
var arr2 = List.of("Dewey", "Stuie");
set.addAll(arr1);
set.addAll(arr2);
System.out.println(set);
> [Huey, Dewey, Louie, Stuie]
```